# Cancan and devise not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I've modified my devise table, User, to have a clearance column. This column is a number (1-3) that represents a user's permissions (read, read/write, full control). Unlike all the examples I'm reading, *my* Clearance (Role in the examples) is not a separate table with a relationship but is its own column in the Devise table (User). Its default value is 1.

My ability.rb looks like this:

```
 class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.clearance.equal?("2")
      can :create, Post
      can :manage, Post, :user_id => user.id
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end

end
```

I've written this off of other examples I've seen (I'm really new to Rails but trying to not ask for help unless absolutely necessary) with the intent that users with a clearance value of 2 can create posts and manage only their posts. I've also included that, because I haven't written the code for 1 and 3 yet, that all other clearance numbers can read everything.

Apperantly, however, Cancan thinks that my user (confirmed clearance level of 2) falls under the "else" provision and therefore I can only read posts. I get a You are not authorized to access this page message if I try to make a new one.
I'm lost. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this be that the clearance column is an integer? in such a case you should write `user.clearance == 2` and not as you wrote.

Comment: That was it. Thanks man. Like I said, I'm new. But I'm learning. I'll check your answer as soon as Stack lets me.